# Streaming from Blazor Wasm is not working expectedly

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have created API Endpoint that streams JSON and deployed it to the Azure App Service. Tested with Curl command from Command Prompt and received stream data correctly one by one after every 5 seconds.

However, I am calling the same API Endpoint from Blazor Wasm, but streaming is not working rather I am receiving the whole data directly. Can anyone tell me where is the problem with the following code in blazor wasm?

```
public async IAsyncEnumerable<ChatMsgDTO> ProcessStreamChatMessage(ChatMsgDTO msgDTO)
        {
            ChatMsgDTO serviceResponseDTO = new();
            var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            using var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "api/ChatMsg/ProcessChatMsgStreaming_TestOnly_withPause");
            request.SetBrowserResponseStreamingEnabled(true); // Enable response streaming
            request.Content = new StringContent(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(msgDTO), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            HttpResponseMessage response = await _http.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);

            using var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = await reader.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
                {
                    
                    Console.WriteLine(line);
                    yield return serviceResponseDTO;
                }
            }
        }
```